# Should I check the dotnet-tools .config directory into source control?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, version-control, dotnet-tool

Recently I've noticed a `.config` directory being created by Visual Studio with a `dotnet-tools.json` file in.  Should this be `.gitignore`d or checked into source control?

Comment: I'm not sure what is this specific config file but your answer is simple. first check the config, if it contains some global configurations that can help other users using your project you should add it to your repo but if it contains any personal information (related to you or your system) you should ignore it.

Comment: for example, I'm using vs-code. I added tasks.json to my repo but ignored settings.json from .vscode folder in my project directory.

Comment: We always ignore the .vscode folder, it mostly contains user specific configuration

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`.config` directory with `dotnet-tools.json` file is created when you install a tool for your project with `dotnet tool install` command. This file `dotnet-tools.json` contains details like version, installation command etc. about all the tools installed for your project. It is more of a local configuration related to setup on local machine. 
If you want your colleague  to install the same tools on her/his machine then you should check-in this file and your colleague is required to clone and run command to restore the same tool on her/his machine. This is very much similar to NuGet packages.

You can safely add this to `.gitignore`. In this case, your collegue will still be able to perform a fresh install of the same tool using `dotnet tool install` with same or different version.

[Here is a good article on this topic](https://andrewlock.net/new-in-net-core-3-local-tools/)

Comment: I would suggest to **always** check in the `dotnet-tools.json`, and use "dotnet tool restore". Background: When you use tools like dotnet-format, test-reports-generation or other tools, they do may not exist on your environment, so may git hooks will fail. Calling local or global dotnet tools are different, so with `dotnet-tools.json` under source control you can "enforce" local usage and avoid polluting your system with global installations. Nice benefit: You see exactly which versions are you using inside the file.

Answer (score 22):

Sometimes Visual Studio creates this file when you simply open the "publish" dialog without even touching any settings. Visual Studio tries to detect EF-migrations/DB-context/etc. in your project by running `dotnet ef -blahblah`; and for that it installs the `ef` tool; and because of that the install generates this file.

If you're not using Entity Framework **not only you're safe to `.gitignore` this file, but you're safe to completely delete it** after closing the "publish" settings dialog (again, if you're not using EF).